# Access controller from $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

When defining an Angular route like

```
.when('text', {
  templateUrl: 'templates/articles/text.html',
  controller: 'MyCtrl'
})
```

and listening to route changes à la

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(next, current) { 
    // yadda yadda
});
```

is it possible to access the controller instance of `MyCtrl` associated with that route change within the `$routeChangeSuccess` event?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would want to do this, as the controller itself will be run once the route has successfully changed anyway. But while it may be redundant, you could access the controller by putting the `$routeChangeSuccess` inside your actual controller.

I am guessing that for whatever reason you want to interact with your controller from another area, in which I suggest doing it through a service, injecting it into both your controller, and the area in which you hook the event.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `$routeChangeSuccess` use the `$stateChangeSuccess`.

Because `$stateChangeSuccess` fired once the state transition is complete.

Comment: I'm not using the ui-router, though.

Comment: We're pretty happy with angular-route-segment for now. Once angular's own new router has landed, we'll use that.

Comment: Angular 2 is coming with plenty of new amazing stuff.